# Pandas keep rows after a condition is true for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have currently the following issue where I'm looking to drop rows in a pandas dataframe before a condition is met. I would like to drop every row prior to the condition of 10 or greater is met in the column "Number", depending on the Name column. Suppose dataframe (df) has two columns called 'Name' and 'Number'. I desire to drop all rows of each unique name before the condition is met, and keep all rows after.

```
Name  Number
Matt    4
Matt    5
Matt    13
Matt    4
Sophie  5 
Sophie  14
Sophie  18
Steve   5
Steve   4
Steve   21 

Desired output: 
Name   Number
Matt    13
Matt    4
Sophie  14
Sophie  18
Steve   21
```

The following code below drops all the items after the condition is met, but this is applied for the entire series / column of values. I would like to do this separately for each unique name occurring. Is there any way to do this, perhaps with a groupby?

```
df[(df['Number'] > 10).argmax():]
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Note: [related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70964954/17242583)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `cummax`. `cummax` converts every False after True into True, so if you `groupby` "Name", it creates a boolean mask where every value after the value greater than 10 is selected:

```
msk = df['Number'].gt(10).groupby(df['Name']).cummax()
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
     Name  Number
2    Matt      13
3    Matt       4
5  Sophie      14
6  Sophie      18
9   Steve      21
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with condition for get greater values like `10` in [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Number'].gt(10).groupby(df['Name']).cummax()]
print (df)
     Name  Number
2    Matt      13
3    Matt       4
5  Sophie      14
6  Sophie      18
9   Steve      21
```

**Detail**: `True`s are repeated to end of group after first match:

```
print (df['Number'].gt(10).groupby(df['Name']).cummax())
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: Number, dtype: bool
```