# python: efficient and pythonic way to get sublist from a descending list which is larger than threshold

Tags: python, iteration, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

Given a list with descending order, e.g. `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -2]` and `threshold = 1.2`, I want to get sublist from original list with all elements larger than `threshold`

Method1:

```py
orgin_lst = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -2]
lst = [i for i in orgin_lst if i > threshold]
```

This is pythonic way but **we don't use the descending property and cannot break out when found a element not larger than threshold**. If there are few satisfied elements but oringal list is very large, the performance is not good.

Method2:

```py
orgin_lst = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -2]
lst = []
for i in orgin_lst:
    if i <= threshold:
        break
    lst.append(i)
```

However this code is not quite pythonic.

Is there a way  that I can combine pythonic style and performance?

Comment: @j1-lee It's part of an interview question. Interviewer wants me to improve best case performance and keep the code clean.

Comment: @j1-lee That other question isn't about a sorted list, and so the answers there don't include the optimal solution for this question. Please reopen. (Or find an actual duplicate... I wouldn't be surprised if there were one.)

Comment: What's the problem with filter? Suppose threshold is 1.2 in my case : `list(filter(lambda x: x>1.2 , orgin_lst))`

Comment: @Shayan Filter will go through whole list and don't use the descending property. Suppose the first element is smaller than threshold, in fact we can get result is empty list in `O(1)` time. However, this method is still `O(n)`

Comment: @maplemaple yeah, I got your point. nice question.

Comment: @j1-lee Thanks. And I just noticed another difference: That other question wanted a *suffix* of the list, while this one wants a *prefix*. Meaning I couldn't even apply my [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965024/12671057)-winner here :-)

Comment: "However this code is not quite pythonic." It's perfectly Pythonic. Pythonic doesn't mean "use list comprehensions everywhere" or "prefer list comprehesnions to for loops". Not at all. Just use the for loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Python 3.10+

Binary search is fast for sorted data, O(log n) time. And Python's `bisect` module already does it. It wants *increasing* data and yours is *decreasing*, but we can virtually make it increasing. Just use its shiny new `key` parameter to negate the O(log n) accessed elements (and search for the negated threshold):

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from operator import neg

i = bisect_left(orgin_lst, -threshold, key=neg)
lst = orgin_lst[:i]
```

Alternatively, use a key function that returns `False` for values larger than the threshold and `True` otherwise. Since `False` is smaller than `True` (they act like `0` and `1`, respectively), we again have a monotonically increasing sequence and can use `bisect` with this:

```
from bisect import bisect

i = bisect(orgin_lst, False, key=lambda x: x <= threshold)
lst = orgin_lst[:i]
```

If you don't need a separate new list, you could use `del orgin_lst[i:]` to instead remove the unwanted elements.

#### Before Python 3.10

Previously I would've written a proxy class to do the job now done by that much more convenient key parameter:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class Negate:
    def __getitem__(_, i):
        return -orgin_lst[i]

i = bisect_left(Negate(), -threshold, 0, len(orgin_lst))
lst = orgin_lst[:i]
```

Or I might've written binary search myself, but I've done that so many times that at some point I started to loathe it.

#### Exponential search

Under your Method1, the list comprehension comparing *every* element, you wrote: *"If there are few satisfied elements but oringal list is very large, the performance is not good"*. If that was not just an argument against that list comprehension but you actually do have mostly *very* few satisfied elements and a *very* long list, then [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) could be better than binary search. But it would be more code (unless you find a package for it, I guess).

A simple iterative search like your Method2 (which I btw do find pythonic) or Chris' answer or with `itertools.takewhile` would also be fast in such extreme cases, but for cases with *large* numbers of satisfied elements, they'd be much slower than binary search and exponential search.

#### `itertools.takewhile`

Like I said it would be slower in general, but it's fast for those best-cases and it's quite simple and clean:

```
from itertools import takewhile

lst = list(takewhile(lambda x: x > threshold, orgin_lst))
```

#### Faster loop

Like I said I do find your loop pythonic, and it's good for best-cases. But calling `append` to individually append elements to the result is quite costly. Would probably be faster to at first just find the first too small element, then find its index and slice:

```
for i in orgin_lst:
    if i <= threshold:
        lst = orgin_lst[:orgin_lst.index(i)]
        break
else:
    lst = orgin_lst[:]
```

Again, if you're ok with just removing the unwanted elements from the existing list, use `del` inside the `if` and then you don't need the `else` part here.

A [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964954/filter-out-everything-before-a-condition-is-met-keep-all-elements-after/71093342#71093342) I wrote for another question ended up second-fastest in the [benchmark there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965024/12671057).

Alternative implementation:

```
cut = None
for i in orgin_lst:
    if i <= threshold:
        cut = orgin_lst.index(i)
        break
lst = orgin_lst[:cut]
```

Comment: this solution also is iterating through each element and doesn't use the sort property! (as you stated "...That key function returns False for all values larger than the threshold and...")

Comment: @Shayan binary search is `O(log n)` to find the spliting pivot which uses descending property, then only copy the required elements.

Comment: @Shayan No, it's binary search, it only looks at very few elements. Let me see whether I can rephrase what you quoted there...

Comment: @Shayan I removed the "all" now and stated the logarithmic runtime. And I had already said "values", not "elements", meaning I'm talking about the key function itself in general, independent from the list. I hope it's clear now?

Comment: it's so cool! I didn't know that. yes, @KellyBundy now it's much better than before.

Comment: Wow, learned a lot from your fantastic answer!!!

Comment: Warning, although it is OK in this case, **you really shouldn't use `threshold.__lt__` or `threshold.__gt__`**. An example of why: `(3).__lt__(0.0)`. Use `operator.lt` with `functools.partial`,instead, or just `lamdbda x: x < threshold`. Magic methods are not direct replacements for the operators that they are associated with, they serve as *hooks used by those operators*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good point. Wasn't thinking about that. I also pretty much never mix different number types. So I suspect in *most* cases it'll be ok. And in most other cases, `float(threshold).__lt__` will be. But I guess the negation method is my best one then.

Comment: @maplemaple Good :-). And I just added yet another section at the end. Just too tired for a new benchmark now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Alright, I switched to lambdas and made the operator.neg solution the first one, that's also better because its explanation is simpler than the bool solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code was very close:

```
orgin_lst = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -2]
lst = []
for i in orgin_lst:
    if i <= threshold:
        break
    lst.append(i)
```

*But* let's employ a generator.

```
def take_until(f, it):
    for x in it:
        if f(x): return
        yield x
```

Now, we can write something like the following, for instance.

```
>>> for x in take_until(lambda x: x <= 1.2, lst):
...     print(x)
...
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
>>>
```

Heck, if we really want a `list`, that's just as easy.

```
>>> list(take_until(lambda x: x <= 1.2, lst))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
>>>
```