# Repeat a list's elements in the same order

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a list, and I want to repeat its elements in the same order.

I want to create `bg` using `sl`.

```
# small list
sl = [10,20]
# from small list, create a big list
bg = [10,10,20,20]
```

I tried:

```
bg = [[i,j] in for i,j in zip([[sl[0]]*2,[sl[1]]*2])]
```

But this gives me:

```
 bg = [[10,20],[10,20]]
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Now I am wondering whether I understood the question right. The provided solution works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
s1 = [10,20]
s2 = np.array(s1).repeat(2)
print(list(s2)) # [10, 10, 20, 20]
```

I could not resist the urge to use `numpy` in such operations. With this function you can repeat not only for single dimensional cases but also in case of matrix or higher order tensors as well.

Comment: My apologies. I just edited my question. How do I get `[10,10,20,20]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import repeat, chain
repetitions = 2

list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(item, repetitions) for item in sl))
```

You can also use a list comprehension, though it's important to note that using multiple `for` clauses in a list comprehension is considered [poor style by some](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#27-comprehensions--generator-expressions):

```py
[item for item in sl for _ in range(repetitions)]
```

This outputs:

```py
[10, 10, 20, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` and `zip`:

```
from itertools import chain
out = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*[sl]*2)))
```

Output:

```py
[10, 10, 20, 20]
```

Since you tagged it pandas, you could use `repeat` as well:

```py
out = pd.Series(sl).repeat(2)
```

Output:

```py
0    10
0    10
1    20
1    20
dtype: int64
```

Comment: pandas seem to be the simple approach. The other one needs new modules import, looks a bit complex. The only thing is I need to convert this `.tolist()`

Comment: okay. Which one do you consider the python way of doing it and takes less time and resources?

Comment: use `np.repeat` if you are keen on performance, unless of course you really need lists, and have no further processing to do

Comment: @sammywemmy new solution using numpy? interesting. How do we do that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what is data type conversion and other types implied here?

Comment: @Mainland I meant Python list, numpy array, pandas Series etc. If you plan to do a simple operation on an object (filtering, indexing etc), the efficiency very much depends on what data type it is. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965024/17521785). If the initial data is a list, then even though numpy is extremely fast, converting the list to numpy array outweighs whatever gains that may be gotten from converting to an array.

Comment: Wrap the list duplication in a list, this should be faster: `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*[[sl]*1000000])))`

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach might be:

```
sl = [10,20]
# from small list, create a big list
bg = []
for ele in sl:
    bg.append(ele)
    bg.append(ele)
print(bg)
```

To make it more generic and incase of more repetitions, you can do:

```
def append_lst(lst, val):
    lst.append(val)

sl = [10,20]
# from small list, create a big list
bg = []
noOfRep = 2
for ele in sl:
    for _ in range(noOfRep):
        append_lst(bg, ele)
    
print(bg)
```

Output:

```
[10, 10, 20, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [10,20]
l2 = l1
l1.extend(l2)
```

output:

```
value of l1:
[10,20,10,20]
```

Comment: My apologies. I just edited my question. How do I get [10,10,20,20] ?